# Why cy.request can not be seen in Chrome DevTools Network tab

Tags: cypress

I am calling multiple cy.request.

Why I can not see them in Chrome DevTool Network tab?

Comment: please add the details with screenshot

Comment: You can click on the step on the test runner to see the details of the request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cy.request()` comes from the test runner, not the app. It bypasses the browser network tab.

See docs for `cy.request' [Debugging](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request#Debugging)

> **Debugging**
>
> **Request is not displayed in the Network Tab of Developer Tools**
>
> Cypress does not actually make an XHR request from the browser. We are actually making the HTTP request from the Cypress Test Runner (in Node). So, you won't see the request inside of your Developer Tools.